# Problems with importing libraries from github in android studio projects

Tags: android, git, github, android-library

I am encountering problems when trying to import libraries from github in android studio projects. Very few libraries are getting imported successfully. Here is my method of importing in android studio project:

Download zip from github.

Extract the respective library.

Import module in android studio project then import the library and adding dependencies.

Here is the error tht I am encountering when I am trying to import material drawer library whose link is:https://github.com/mikepenz/MaterialDrawer

```
   Error:No such property: GROUP for class: org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.ant.DefaultGroovyMavenDeployer
```

Is my method of importing libraries from github correct?

This is my module gradle.

```
  apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

  android {
compileSdkVersion 22
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.works.vipul.materialdrawer"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 22
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

 dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:3.1.2@aar') {
    transitive = true
}


}
```

Comment: use gradle instead of doing it manually..

Comment: I am adding dependencies frm gradle and compiling it with gradle. I dont know what u mean by doing it manually

Comment: You mentioned downloading zip and import libs, did you tried this compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:3.1.2@aar') {
    transitive = true
} in your build.gradle

Comment: I did add this in dependencies

Comment: add library in your project dependencies, that will automatically added to module gradle file.

Comment: But I havent for jar file for this library I have to import module thus.

Comment: Why is it always giving me some error and not importing successfully?

Comment: did below answer worked for you ?

Comment: I am updating my android studio. Gimme 7 mins more

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should resolve **materialdrawer** dependency by gradle.

Add these in your build.gradle under repositories

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral() //add this line 
}
```

also add this under your **dependencies**

```
compile('com.mikepenz:materialdrawer:3.1.2@aar') {
    transitive = true
}
```

Comment: I did add tht but still getting the same error Error:No such property: GROUP for class: org.gradle.api.publication.maven.internal.deployer.DefaultGroovyMavenDeployer

Comment: do you have 'gradle-mvn-push.gradle' in your build.gradle anywhere? if yes try removing that line

Comment: Grt man it worked but what is gradle-mvn-push.gradle' and why was it hindering build